# How to test EOF on io.Reader in Go?

Tags: file, go, io, eof

The Go's `io.Reader` documentation states that a `Read()` may return a non zero `n` value and an `io.EOF` at the same time. Unfortunately, the `Read()` method of a `File` doesn't do that.

When the EOF is reached and some bytes could still be read, the Read method of file returns non zero `n` and `nil` error. It is only when we try to read when already at the end of the file that we get back zero `n` and `io.EOF` as error.

I couldn't find a simple method to test if the EOF is reached without trying to read data from the file. If we perform a Read() with a buffer of 0 byte, we get back zero `n` and `nil` error although we are at the end of file.

To avoid this last read, the only solution I have found is to keep track myself of the number of bytes remaining to read in the file. Is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: not AFAIK. you can maybe use seek or something to get the current position but since it will require way more syscalls it will be slower.

Comment: Why not make a type that _always_ reads some bytes and returns EOF?

Comment: @JimB That's an amazing trick. I'll adopt that solution. But instead of the read ahead, I'll keep track of the bytes remaining to read so I can return io.EOF just in time. The reason I like it most is that I don't need to modify code anywhere in my program. I only need to provide a wrapper to File.  If you write a nice answer with the two options, I'll grant it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new type, that keeps track of the number of bytes read so far. Then, at EOF check time, you could compare the expected number of bytes read with the actual number of bytes read. Here is a sample implementation. The `eofReader` keeps track of the number of bytes read and compares it to the file size, in case the underlying type is a file:

```
package main

// ... imports 

// eofReader can be checked for EOF, without a Read. 
type eofReader struct {
    r     io.Reader
    count uint64
}

// AtEOF returns true, if the number of bytes read equals the file size.
func (r *eofReader) AtEOF() (bool, error) {
    f, ok := r.r.(*os.File)
    if !ok {
        return false, nil
    }
    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    return r.Count() == uint64(fi.Size()), nil
}

// Read reads and counts.
func (r *eofReader) Read(buf []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.r.Read(buf)
    atomic.AddUint64(&r.count, uint64(n))
    return n, err
}

// Count returns the count.
func (r *eofReader) Count() uint64 {
    return atomic.LoadUint64(&r.count)
}
```

You could use this type by wrapping any reader in an eofReader:

```
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("main.go")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    r := &eofReader{r: f}
    log.Println(r.AtEOF())

    if _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(r.AtEOF())
}

// 2016/12/19 03:49:35 false <nil>
// 2016/12/19 03:49:35 true <nil>
```

Code as [gist](https://gist.github.com/miku/6e9cdb5225a1814f1758d3b6793ae423).